# How to change multiple parameters in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

How to redirect and change last one in subfolder if querystring has multiple parameters. If in case of only one parameter removing subfolder ? I can redirect only one, but when I tried for two parameters, it become messed.

```
localhost/mynews/category.php?cat=news
localhost/mynews/category.php?cat=news&subcat=9
```

To

```
localhost/mynews/news
localhost/mynews/news/9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in `mynews/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mynews/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category\.php\?cat=([\w-]+)&subcat=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category\.php\?cat=([\w-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks god you came, url couldn't redirect while testing different ways and answers, now URL is redirected with your answer but why I face object not found page

Comment: Does `localhost/mynews/news/9` directly work in a browser?

Comment: No, only `localhost/mynews/category.php?cat=news&subcat=9` works `localhost/mynews/news/9` doesn't work

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ category.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [NC,L]`    URl is rewritten using this rule, but I can't redirect with this

Comment: removing `^mynews/` and using `RewriteBase /mynews/` finally works for me. Thanks, very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, in the .htaccess you could do the next:

```
Rewriterule ^mynews/(.+)/(.+)$ category.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
```

Where the `(.+)` represent each value after the `$`.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing change, still same url